# RewriteRule containing dots does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a simple rewrite rule to correct some 404s on a site I work on, but the redirect is not functioning correctly. I am trying to redirect www.site.com/eve.. to www.site.com/ with any the below (each tried separately):

```
RewriteRule ^eve..$ http://www.site.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^eve.. http://www.site.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^eve\.\.$ http://www.site.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^eve\.\. http://www.site.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^eve\.\./?$ http://www.site.com/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

None are successful. However the following does work:

```
RewriteRule ^eve http://www.site.com/ [R=301,L]
```

But this rule is too generic and I want to exactly match the redirects to prevent future issues.
what is wrong with my attempts to redirect the exact URL?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the dots like this:

```
RewriteRule ^eve\.\./?$ http://www.site.com/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Dot `.` means any character and your string `eve..` can match `every` or `eve11` as well.

Comment: I just tried this, it does not appear to be working either unfortunately

Comment: I tested this `RewriteRule ^eve\.\./?$ http://www.site.com/ [R=301,L,NC]` and it is working fine here. Can you show me matching lines from your error.log?

Comment: I don't have any errors, it just doesn't redirect when I attempt to load that page - I am on windows 7 with xampp if that helps, this is my development environment

Comment: ugh, I tested this on a linux machine and it works fine - it seems to be an environment issue. Thanks!

Comment: Ah WIndows.. I got hold of my wife's Windows 7 laptop with XAMPP installed. And when I tried this rule there I found that Apache server there is mysteriously stripping out `\.\.` thus trying to load a URI `/eve`. So if you add a new rule `RewriteRule ^eve/?$ http://www.site.com/ [R=301,L,NC]` it will have same effect on XAMPP on Windows.